# AWS Cognito + React Native Social Sign In Getting "An Error Has Occurred"

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, oauth-2.0

I am using React Native + Expo to do Social Sign in Via. Cognito.

Everything is configured correctly, I know this because it worked, and after no change, it stopped working prompting an error.

I find it intresting because when I am in Cognito and I click 'launch hosted UI', it still works, but using my app displays the following error:

[image]

My `aws-exports.js` looks like (cut only important info):

```
 "oauth": {
        "domain": "upliftXXXXXXXX.us-west-2.amazoncognito.com",
        "scope": [
            "phone",
            "email",
            "openid",
            "profile",
            "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/",
        "redirectSignOut": "exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/",
        "responseType": "code"
    },
```

and my cognito setup is:

[image]

also, i am using basic sign-up/sign-in calls, all followed by https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social/q/platform/react-native/#setup-frontend